# How to add an IDE Platform to your reactjs Web App

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have been searching on the internet on how one can add an IDE/Text Editior on a reactJS project that can run Java and Python if possible even more languages... So I was looking to having something like Khan Academy or DataCamp, so I want to be able to also monitor that inputs and outputs so I can make it interactive and when the answer is wrong and then alert wrong answer something like that...

How can I go about this or where can I read about making such?

Comment: I think first you need to take a computer science class, then come back here to explain your problem.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-OxzIC6pic this is a good start

Comment: @SangĐặng Don't worry about that, I have already enrolled at my University for that, note that everyone will not know everything man regardless of studying Computer Science or not. Hence stackoverflow is here to ask for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a front-end development specific question.

For such an react-application to work, first you should create a backend which will run your python/java script, then expose a api to link with react application. Which will take the program as request data and return program ouput as response.

Comment: I think I am getting the sense of what you saying, correct me if I am wrong on how to approach this based on what you said. So since I will be using NodeJs as my Back-end right so I am to process that user-input(Java or Python Script) then I believe there's an Api that can help me process that right? An then return response to the client with regards to output? And for realtime interaction will pusher do the trick?

Comment: since you are using Node.js backend, your program will only be able to parse JavaScript. But there are packages like "https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell" which can parse python program within node.js

My actual comment is that, in the same node server which you are using as backend, you can have sandboxes(without access to all system internals) of java python or any programming language compilers. so when your api will call the javacompiler with maybe exec() node command and send the output back as a response.

Comment: I will look into this thanks for your input really made a difference in the way I see this problem.